# How to get the login value of the id and pass that to the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

So i have a login page that is using the membership class.. what i am trying to do is get the username that they pass in and once they are authorised immediatly i would like the username to be passed into a stored proc to show the relevant data for that user.. At the moment, when the user has logged in they are taken to the next page, but i want the info for that user to be ready straight away.. im new to coding and not sure how to do it... What i have so far... 
LOGIN PAGE...

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                // This is an unauthorized, authenticated request...
                Response.Redirect("~/UnauthorizedAccess.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        //Validating against the user store
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
        }

        //if we get here then the credentials were invalid
        InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

login page works fine but not sure how to divert to the supplier page and automatically pass the username in to my stored procedure (The stored procedure is working fine in sql, but i dont know how to get it to pass param.)

Here is the page i want to divert to and automatically show my stored procedure..

```
public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int VendorId { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void RefreshGrid(int VendorId)
    {
        try
        {
            //get list of records from vendorId 
            BizManager biz = new BizManager();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt = biz.GetMaterialAndDesc(VendorId);

            SupplierView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            SupplierView.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrMsg = App.App.HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, "Application Failed adding products to the list");
        }
    }

    private string ErrMsg
    {
        get { return ErrMsgUpdate.Text; }
        set { ErrMsgUpdate.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
User.Identity.Name
```

That gives you the Username

Or if you are in a Class somewher use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```